# Read string with name value to extract values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a string which is passed through ajax to php so that values can be read and stored in database.

The string is like:

```
venuetypes[]=1&venuetypes[]=2&venuetypes[]=3
```

How do i read this in `foreach` or any other way which would fetch me the values?
Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parse_str`:

```
parse_str($string, $parsed);

foreach ($parsed['venuetypes'] as $type) {
    // do something with $type
}
```

Comment: the string that i posted in the answer is stored in a variable. How can i do with that?

Comment: How are you storing it in a variable? If it was sent as the parameter string in AJAX, it will be parsed automatically by PHP. You need to show your code.

Comment: it was stored in a vairable as a post parameter, sent through ajax. the string is stored in like $a, then how can i iterate through the values from there, i tried parse_str but it makes it like {"venuetypes":["1","2","3"]}, how do i play with this>

Comment: If that's in `$var`, `$var['venuetypes']` will be an array, just like `$_POST['venuetypes']` in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$str= "venuetypes[]=1&venuetypes[]=2&venuetypes[]=3";
parse_str($str, $data);

foreach($data['venuetypes'] as $key=>$val){
}
```

Comment: pars_str gives an array but it is not itereating the values through foreach

Comment: this gives {"venuetypes":["1","2","3"]}. Now how can i iterate over this?

Comment: answer updated.
it will result Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the value through reserved variables such as `$_POST` or `$_GET`, they are automatically parsed as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use parse_str();

```
$get_string = "venuetypes[]=1&venuetypes[]=2&venuetypes[]=3";
parse_str($get_string, $get_array);
print_r($get_array);`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
<?php
$yourstring = "venuetypes[]=1&venuetypes[]=2&venuetypes[]=3";
parse_str($yourstring, $array);
$key=key($array);
$count=count($array[$key]);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
echo $array['venuetypes'][$i];
echo "</br>";
}
```